# Not updating SQLite table row when a certain column has been updated

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

In my android SQLite project I have a trigger where I want to update the OrderNumber of a product to -1 when any columns other than the OrderNumber have been changed. I have created the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Reset_OrderNumber AFTER UPDATE
ON Products
BEGIN
   IF NOT UPDATE(OrderNumber)
   BEGIN
        UPDATE Products SET OrderNumber = -1 WHERE OrderNumber = NEW.OrderNumber;
   END
END
GO
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "IF": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:     CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Reset_OrderNumber AFTER UPDATE
    ON Products
    BEGIN
       IF NOT UPDATE(OrderNumber)
       BEGIN
            UPDATE Products SET OrderNumber = -1 WHERE OrderNumber = NEW.OrderNumber;
       END
    END
    GO
```

What am I doing wrong? Is "IF NOT UPDATE" not available in Sqlite synthax? And if so is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), the only statements allowed in a trigger body are 
update/insert/delete/select statements.

To restrict the trigger to certain columns, you have to list all those columns on which the trigger should trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Reset_OrderNumber
AFTER UPDATE OF ID, Name, other, columns, [...] ON Products
BEGIN
    UPDATE Products SET OrderNumber = -1 WHERE OrderNumber = NEW.OrderNumber;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the SQLite syntax in https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html and https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/update-stmt.html, you can't have `IF` after `BEGIN`, but

```
ON Products
WHEN <condition>
BEGIN
   UPDATE ...
```

is allowed.